# Can you use more concentrated hydrogen peroxide solution for obtaining iodine from PVP-I?

Tags: concentration

In [NileRed —
Making iodine](https://youtu.be/FNf8PSda7iI?t=138) video Nigel Braun extracts iodine from the medical povidone-iodine. He says that the quantities of hydrogen peroxide needed is $\pu{500 ml}$ of $3\,\%$ hydrogen peroxide.

I did the calculation, and found out that it contains $\pu{15 ml}$ of hydrogen peroxide diluted with water. Can I use $\ce{167 ml}$ of $9\,\%$ hydrogen peroxide since $\pu{167 ml}\times 0.09 = \pu{15.0 ml},$ e.g. the same amount of $\ce{H2O2}$?

Comment: I remember near identical question posted recently here. You can, if you use also 333 mL of water. Otherwise there may or may not play role the different concentration and total volume.

Comment: It may provide better iodine yield with lower volume of more concentrated peroxide. But generally, it is always good to try to reproduce the procedure exactly, unless you do know very well why you intentionally deviate.

Comment: So do I need to use the same amount of water and the same amount of h2o2 or just the same amount of the 9%? Does the amount of water matter?

Comment: What is your interpretation of *reproduce the procedure exactly, unless you do know very well why you intentionally deviate.*  ? // BTW, I remember seeing near exactly same question recently here.

Comment: It's just I have 9% hydrogen peroxide and I want to use it instead of diluting it

Comment: Then try it. // Note that SE questions are supposed to be self-contained, giving sense even without link content, which should provide just additional information or refer to info source. CH SE site users are not big fans of watching youtube links to understand question. You should recreate the procedure by words here.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just mentioned the source. Because SE site users like to see resources too

Comment: Yes, they do, together with explicitly written essential content of the linked material, in this case the discussed procedure of iodine production, not to be forced to watch the video to realize, if the missing water would or would not matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135734/discussion-between-itamar-cohen-and-poutnik).